# Heyzap Fyber integration Adobe Air

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, heyzap, fyber

I'm trying to integrate the Heyzap SDK 10 to my AdobeAIR iOS project with no luck. I could start the services using the SDK 9 but with the new SDK I just get a "Fyber Version 8.5.2 - Waiting for SDK to start" when I try to open the mediation test suit.

I followed the documentation step by step and most likely implemented everything as supposed to be. Do you have any clue on this issue?

I'm using
Adobe Flash Professional CS6
AIR 23.0.0.274
Latest Heyzap SDK 10
Starling

Thanks,
Gionathan

Comment: Hi Pesaresi, Do you have any success with Heyzap integration? I'm also stuck like you.

Answer (score 1):

In general this message just means the SDK hasn't started yet. Solving this usually involves confirming your dashboard settings are correct, making sure the bundle ID of your app matches your dashboard, or contacting support if these things don't work.

Comment: the OP contacted Heyzap support and his issue was resolved.